# JQuery multiple IDs

Tags: jquery, uniqueidentifier

If I'm attaching a unique ID to `#Atest1`, `#Atest2`, does this make sense?

```
var percent = Math.round (($("#Atest1, #Atest2"+id).val()));
```

Comment: what is `id`, lets say `id = foo` then I believe the string would evaluate to `"#Atest1, #Atest2foo` so to me no this doesn't make sense unless `id` is meant to be a dynamic assignment of what would be part of the second elements `id` attribute you wish to wrap.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I guess I didn't make that clear.  ID is just an incremented number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `val()` will return the value of the first matched element. So,

```
$("#Atest1, #Atest2"+id).val()
```

it's practically equivalent with:

```
$("#Atest1").val()
```

Comment: How might I rewrite this then?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I guess $.each could help in your case.

Comment: You will want to use the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each) or [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map) this will loop you through the objects to the values that you need.

Comment: How might this look using .each?  var percent = Math.round (($("#A, #cp-Personnel_AuthorizedStrength"+id).val() / $("#B, #cp-Personnel_AssignedStrength"+id).val()) * 100);